# ESTA query ticked no on transit query

Tags: usa, canada, esta, stopovers

Recently had my eTa and ESTA applications approved/authorized for my travel to Canada and the US.

I hit no on the query regarding transit. Thinking I had to enter my hotel details for the US. Because I'm going back. After a stay in canada, I'm first flying in to Vancouver with a 6 hour stopover in LA, then heading back to the US 15 days later for a week in NY, anyone know if this will be an issue?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You got this right.

You should only say your purpose is "Transit" if your only purpose is to transit. If you are spending a week in New York then transit is not your only purpose.

Comment: We just got a question from someone else in the same situation who did indicate "transit": [Should I change my ESTA from transit to visit?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/183281/should-i-change-my-esta-from-transit-to-visit).  Since there isn't a requirement to modify this response for a subsequent visit or transit on the same ESTA, I think "got this right" may be a bit strong.  Indicating "no" for transit in this case is probably better, but indicating "yes" is also reasonable because it is true of the first visit, and I doubt CBP would object.